# Homomorphic Evaluation of Pseudo Random Function

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, pseudo-random-function

I'm looking for a special Pseudo Random Function (PRF) $F_k()$ which follows the below.

For fully homomorphic encryption (FHE), $\mathit{FHE}(F_k(x)) = F_k(\mathit{FHE}(x))$.

Or is there any homomorphically evaluable doubling pseudorandom number generator algorithm? (because Goldreich-Goldwasser-Micali PRF construction is based on the doubling pseudorandom number generator.)

Thanks.

Comment: Do mean encryption of x by FHE(x) ?

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira Yes, I meant it.

Comment: I assume FHE has to have some key, say $\kappa$.  Suppose the family $\{F_k\}_k$ has the property that for _any_ $\kappa$ and $k$, $\mathit{FHE}_\kappa(F_k(x)) = F_k(\mathit{FHE}_\kappa(x))$.  Now I can trivially distinguish $F_k$ for uniform random $k$ from a uniform random function $G$.  If this is the property you mean, then the answer is no, this is a contradiction in terms.  So you'll need to be a little more specific if that's not the property you want!

Comment: What does "=" mean in the context of your question? Do you mean the ciphertexts are equal or that the ciphertexts are encryptions of the same plaintext?

Comment: @mikeazo I meant the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an Eurocrypt'15 [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/687) published by Albrecht et al. which creates a cipher minimizing the number of multiplications needed to produce an encryption. This cipher is called LowMC and it can also be used as a PRF with almost same parameters as in the block-cipher - check out LowMC section in this [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/542).

Fortunately, there is open-source [code](https://bitbucket.org/malb/lowmc-helib) which evaluates LowMC homomorphically with HElib. To evaluate the cipher homomorphically is to compute $\mathsf{Enc}_{\mathsf{k}}(\mathsf{LowMC}(x))$ from $\mathsf{Enc}_\mathsf{k}(x)$.

So you can plug in the PRF parameters given by Grassi et al. (for 128 bit PRF security) in the script provided by Albrecht and there you have it: LowMC becomes a PRF and your question is solved - compute $\mathsf{Enc}_\mathsf{k}(\mathsf{PRF}(x))$ from $\mathsf{Enc}_\mathsf{k}(x)$. And I think this is the state of the art for computing PRFs in HE land.